# Combining rows in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have an sql query:

```
select el as COL_1, sum(volume) as COL_2 
from table1
where el like 'False%' and Month = 'SEP' and year(RollUpDate) = '2014' group by el
union
select el as COL_1, sum(volume) as COL_2 
from table1
where el = 'True' and Month = 'SEP' and year(RollUpDate) = '2014' group by el
```

which will bring back:

```
true   | 12
false a| 12
false b| 13
false 2| 3
```

What I am trying to do is combine the falses so that I can bring back a clearer result with one false and a sum of the false volume
i.e.

```
true   | 12
false  | 55
```

Any help appreciated, sql server 2008 btw

EDIT: Well, these solutions are great and most work as described but I cannot use them with the rigid jdbc set up, so I cannot use case statements. Jarlh's answer is close but when a null result is returned it still has those columns which have been created, if there was a simple way for this to return null by not using case statements it would be perfect

Comment: Side note: by calling functions on `RollUpDate`, you can't use indices to speed comparisons for that column.  If you did a range query ([inclusive lower-bound, exclusive upper-bound](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)), you could use an index trivially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 'False' as COL_1, sum(volume) as COL_2 
from table1 where el like 'False%' and Month = 'SEP' and year(RollUpDate) = '2014'
union all
select 'True' as COL_1, sum(volume) as COL_2 
from table1
where el = 'True' and Month = 'SEP' and year(RollUpDate) = '2014'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your query as it would be a table, and select from it pretty much the same as you would from a regular or temp table.

```
SELECT t.COL_1, sum(t.COL_2) FROM
    ((select el as COL_1, sum(volume) as COL_2 
    from table1
    where el like 'False%' and Month = 'SEP' and year(RollUpDate) = '2014' group by el)
    union all
    (select el as COL_1, sum(volume) as COL_2 
    from table1
    where el = 'True' and Month = 'SEP' and year(RollUpDate) = '2014' group by el)) t
WHERE t.COL_1 = 'false'
GROUP BY t.COL_1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery and aggregation:

```
select col_1, sum(Col_2)
from ((select el as COL_1, sum(volume) as COL_2 
       from table1
       where el like 'False%' and Month = 'SEP' and year(RollUpDate) = '2014'
       group by el
      ) union all
      (select el as COL_1, sum(volume) as COL_2 
       from table1
       where el = 'True' and Month = 'SEP' and year(RollUpDate) = '2014'
       group by el
      )
     ) t
group by col_1;
```

However, this is overly complicated.  You can just do:

```
select (case when el like 'False%' then 'false'
             else 'True'
        end) as COL_1, sum(volume) as COL_2 
from table1
where (el = 'True' or el like 'False%') and Month = 'SEP' and year(RollUpDate) = '2014'
group by (case when el like 'False%' then 'false'
               else 'True'
          end)
```

That is, you don't need the `union` at all.  Just use a `case` statement for the column used for aggregation.

EDIT:

Actually, the original query distinguishes between the various forms of "false".  The previous query is probably what the OP wants, but the following is more equivalent to the original query:

```
select el as COL_1, sum(volume) as COL_2 
from table1
where (el = 'True' or el like 'False%') and Month = 'SEP' and year(RollUpDate) = '2014'
group by el;
```

Comment: 2nd option is much better

Answer (score 0):

Well, although all of the answers were correct, they weren't exactly what I was looking for although @Jarlh got close.

I wanted to make a temporary column that provided the true and false rows but that did not appear when the volume row was null.
This is what I ended up with:

```
    select 'False' as COL_1, coalesce(sum(volume),0) as COL_2 from tl1 where el like 'False%' and Month = :month and year(RollUpDate) = :year having sum(Volume) is not null 
union 
select 'True' as COL_1, coalesce(sum(volume),0) as COL_2 from tbl1 where el = 'True' and Month = :month and year(RollUpDate) = :year having sum(Volume) is not null
```